# Android: SQLite database crashes on returning a quantity

Tags: android, sqlite

Database holds name and quantity of medication... what is required to be returned is the quantity corresponding to the medication which is scanned.
code for database:

```
public class ToolDB {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_QUANTITY = "quantity";
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Medicine_Database";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "meds_db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table if not exists meds_db (id integer primary key autoincrement, "
             + "name VARCHAR not null, quantity VARCHAR);";


    public String QuantReturn(){

        UserInput x = new UserInput();
        String y = x.QRcodeReturn();

        String quantity=null;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT quantity FROM meds_db WHERE name = " + y;
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if(null != c && c.moveToFirst()){
            quantity  = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUANTITY));
        }
        return quantity;
    }
```

QRcodeReturn() method works when you run it on its own and it returns the proper string read from a QR code.

class that crashes when executed:

```
public class Testing extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_testing);

    ToolDB db = new ToolDB(this);

         db.open();
         String c1 = db.QuantReturn();
         db.close();


         TextView t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.slot4);
         t3.setText(c1);

}
```

Logcat where the error occurs:

```
03-18 21:24:58.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14192): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 21:24:58.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14192): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.SurgicalMate/com.example.SurgicalMate.Testing}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 21:24:58.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14192):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
03-18 21:24:58.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14192):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
03-18 21:24:58.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14192):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
03-18 21:24:58.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14192):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
03-18 21:24:58.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14192):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-18 21:24:58.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14192):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
03-18 21:24:58.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14192):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
03-18 21:24:58.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14192):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 21:24:58.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14192):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-18 21:24:58.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14192):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
03-18 21:24:58.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14192):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
03-18 21:24:58.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14192):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-18 21:24:58.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14192): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 21:24:58.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14192):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:153)
03-18 21:24:58.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14192):    at com.example.SurgicalMate.UserInput.QRcodeReturn(UserInput.java:76)
03-18 21:24:58.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14192):    at com.example.SurgicalMate.ToolDB.QuantReturn(ToolDB.java:78)
03-18 21:24:58.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14192):    at com.example.SurgicalMate.Testing.onCreate(Testing.java:24)
03-18 21:24:58.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14192):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
03-18 21:24:58.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14192):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
03-18 21:24:58.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14192):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
03-18 21:24:58.310: E/AndroidRuntime(14192):    ... 11 more
```

QRcodeReturn() method returns a string.. I have tested it elsewhere and it has worked correctly.

```
public String QRcodeReturn(){

    SharedPreferences codeHack = getSharedPreferences(SCAN_RESULT,0);
    String QRcode = codeHack.getString("entry", "unregistered");

    return QRcode;
}
```

Comment: On this line `TextView t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.slot4);`, are you absolutely sure t3 is not null?

Comment: Would you mind telling what's in Line 76 of UserInput.java?

Comment: Positive. Already tested using a constant in the selectQuery instead of variable and it displays the correct quantity.

Comment: I think this is this line `String y = x.QRcodeReturn();` what is `QRcodeReturn()` method?

Comment: line 76 is part of QRcodeReturn() method which i will update to main post now

Comment: Can you post the code of `QRcodeReturn()` and point to line 76?

Comment: line 76 is the sharedpreferences line which i have updated in main post now in QRcodeReturn() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QRcodeReturn()` as it is now will only work correctly if it has a proper `Context` (it needs it for `getSharedPreferences()` metod to work). It won't work from class `ToolDB.

You should :

- either pass a `Context` parameter to it
- or alternatively run this method from your activity before using `ToolDB` class and pass the obtained value to `ToolDB` class.

For example:

```
public String QRcodeReturn(Context context){

    SharedPreferences codeHack = context.getSharedPreferences(SCAN_RESULT,0);
    String QRcode = codeHack.getString("entry", "unregistered");

    return QRcode;
}
```

You can then use it from the activity:

```
String code = QRcodeReturn(this);
```

and from `QuantReturn()`:

```
public String QuantReturn(Context context){

   ...
   String y = x.QRcodeReturn(context);
   ...
}
```

Comment: how and where do i pass the context parameter?

Comment: the QRcodeReturn method is in a seperate class (not ToolDB class) so when i use String code = QRcodeReturn(this); in the ToolDB class i get an error saying it is undefined for ToolDB

Comment: now when i call QuantReturn() in a completely different class should i do it like this? ToolDB db = new ToolDB(this);
  
    db.open();
    String c1 = db.QuantReturn(this.getApplicationContext());
    db.close();  --- because this still resulted in the app crashing

Comment: Well, I don't have the code for the other class. If the other class is Activity, you can just call it as db.QuantReturn(this);

Comment: actually the class is posted in my main post (class Testing extends Activity) thats the class that crashes