# Android: Why is my app crashing when this class is called?

Tags: android, sqlite

2 classes involved here................
the method from another class (a SQLitedatabase):

```
public String QuantReturn(){

        Testing x = new Testing();
        String code = x.QRcodeReturn();

        String quantity=null;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT quantity FROM meds_db WHERE name = " + code;
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if(null != c && c.moveToFirst()){
            quantity  = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUANTITY));
        }
        return quantity;
    }
```

and the class that crashes when called..................................................

```
public class Testing extends Activity {


public static final String SCAN_RESULT = "MyPreferencesFile";

public String QRcodeReturn(){

    SharedPreferences codeHack = getSharedPreferences(SCAN_RESULT,0);
    String QRcode = codeHack.getString("entry", "unregistered");

    return QRcode;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_testing);


         ToolDB db = new ToolDB(this);
         String c1 = db.QuantReturn();

         TextView t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.slot4);
         t3.setText(c1);

}
```

Logcat of the erros occuring as a result of crash:

```
03-19 13:59:08.517: E/AndroidRuntime(10579): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 13:59:08.517: E/AndroidRuntime(10579): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.SurgicalMate/com.example.SurgicalMate.Testing}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 13:59:08.517: E/AndroidRuntime(10579):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
03-19 13:59:08.517: E/AndroidRuntime(10579):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
03-19 13:59:08.517: E/AndroidRuntime(10579):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
03-19 13:59:08.517: E/AndroidRuntime(10579):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
03-19 13:59:08.517: E/AndroidRuntime(10579):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-19 13:59:08.517: E/AndroidRuntime(10579):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
03-19 13:59:08.517: E/AndroidRuntime(10579):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
03-19 13:59:08.517: E/AndroidRuntime(10579):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 13:59:08.517: E/AndroidRuntime(10579):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-19 13:59:08.517: E/AndroidRuntime(10579):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
03-19 13:59:08.517: E/AndroidRuntime(10579):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
03-19 13:59:08.517: E/AndroidRuntime(10579):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-19 13:59:08.517: E/AndroidRuntime(10579): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 13:59:08.517: E/AndroidRuntime(10579):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:153)
03-19 13:59:08.517: E/AndroidRuntime(10579):    at com.example.SurgicalMate.Testing.QRcodeReturn(Testing.java:23)
03-19 13:59:08.517: E/AndroidRuntime(10579):    at com.example.SurgicalMate.ToolDB.QuantReturn(ToolDB.java:76)
03-19 13:59:08.517: E/AndroidRuntime(10579):    at com.example.SurgicalMate.Testing.onCreate(Testing.java:38)
03-19 13:59:08.517: E/AndroidRuntime(10579):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
03-19 13:59:08.517: E/AndroidRuntime(10579):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
03-19 13:59:08.517: E/AndroidRuntime(10579):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
03-19 13:59:08.517: E/AndroidRuntime(10579):    ... 11 more
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: How is this different from your earlier question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22494623/android-sqlite-database-crashes-on-returning-a-quantity

Comment: Add a breakpoint at SharedPreferences codeHack = getSharedPreferences(SCAN_RESULT,0); and check whether its return null.

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the shared preferences AFTER `onCreate` is called. Or else the context would be null.

Comment: placing the method after the OnCreate method did not help. Still crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
public String QRcodeReturn(){

    SharedPreferences codeHack = getSharedPreferences(SCAN_RESULT,0);
    if (codeHack != null) {
        String QRcode = codeHack.getString("entry", "unregistered");
        return QRcode;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Because what I see is, **codeHack** is null and you are trying to call **getString** of null object.

Answer (score 0):

Your getSharedPreferences() method is returning null - as a result of this, codeHack resolves to null and further operations on this String throw the null pointer exception. Most likely, your preferences file has not been set up correctly.

Comment: I have tested the QRcodeReturn() method on its own and it does return the correct string. The problem is when i go through QuantReturn() method to pass the string there, it crashes.

Comment: Can you debug using breakpoints and let me know if the line rawQuery is throwing the error (means db has not been initialized properly) or the quantity line is throwing the error. Can you place breakpoints in that method and post at which line the error is thrown?